# `password_verify` call returning false for correct password

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt, crypt

I have the following snippet of code:

```
// bcrypt hash of 'password'
$hash = '$2y$10$4u0cQ.WEnwHDo.C5Nl1vm.shKA0beQ32wqzphSfzklAq9OcDM2nLu';
if(password_verify('password', $hash)) {
    print_r('woohoo!');
}
else {
    print_r('fubar');
}
```

On one server it's working fine (woohoo!), on another it doesn't work. [I've just put it up on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/2W0d9z7Q) and it fails there too.

The problem is (as can be see on that codepad page) that the hash computed by `crypt` is of length 13 instead of the required 60.

I'm using [ircmaxel's password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) on github to implement the PHP 5.5 only `password_verify` function.

Comment: Different systems ahve different crypt algorithms installed, so they might use different algorithms. If you don't specify which unexpected things may happen. You have to check first which type of encryption has been used before you can decrypt or compare.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? (I assume 5.3 or 5.4, since lib only works for those versions, but can you specify the exact version on each machine you're testing?)

Comment: It's working on 5.3.14 and not working on 5.2.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are running the script on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7, and therefore the algorithm '2y' is not yet known.

If possible, i would consider to do a PHP upgrade on this server, the '2y' parameter solves a problem with unicode input strings.

Should this not be an option, then you can replace the algorithm in the compatibility pack. Somewhere about line 49 you will find...

```
$hash_format = sprintf("$2y$%02d$", $cost);
```

...change it to the former BCrypt constant '2a'...

```
$hash_format = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost);
```

...this is of course not optimal, but it is the best you can do on earlier versions.

A new generated password hash will now start with `'$2a$10$...'` and the verification with this hash-value should work on every system.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately the server it's not working on doesn't have bcrypt at all because it's running PHP 5.2.17 and only in 5.3 did PHP begin to have its own implementation of bcrypt.

Comment: @Matt - Ahh yes, well then you should have a look at the [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library, they claim to work with PHP 3 and later, though they will probably fallback to something different. The [Suhoshin-Pack](http://www.hardened-php.net/) should also add an implementation of BCrypt. And of course, an update of the server will be a good thing...