# Using crypt () blowfish hash during login

Tags: php, hash

*** A REAL WORKING ANSWER is at the bottom of this page! ***

This is a question about using crypt () blowfish hash during login for customer verification. I am restricted to PHP 5.3 by my web host and I know it would be better to use PHP 5.5 with password hash () and password verify() but PHP 5.3 doesn’t seem to recognize them. The problem is not hashing the password and putting it in the database the available codes on line work for that. The problem is all the codes I found (about ten so far) don’t take into consideration that the randomized salt that is highly recommended for the registration page can’t be used on login passwords because it will be different every time with no match. Is what I am trying to do not possible on PHP 5.3 or is there a way to re-hash the users password using the salt it was randomized with so it can be checked against the one stored in the database?

Codes like this work well for randomizing the salt and hashing the password for the database entry.

```
function better_crypt($input, $rounds = 9)
 {
   $salt = "";
   $salt_chars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9));
   for($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) {
    $salt .= $salt_chars[array_rand($salt_chars)];
  }
   return crypt($input, sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
 }
   $password_hash = better_crypt($input);
```

But login codes like this don’t work and the functions from the registration page must be redefined on the login page some how. They don’t carry over like session variables. I know I must be missing something… Does anyone have a code that will work for this funtion?

```
 $password_hash = better_crypt($db_password_hash);

  if (crypt($user_password, $password_hash) == $password_hash) {
  echo '<br>';  
  echo 'true';
  }else{
  echo '<br>';  
  echo 'false';
  }
```

Can’t add comment at bottom of page… I don’t have permission?

The “better crypt” function is for the registration page, it could be called something else. I don’t think it is used for the login page or the PHP include page, but this is what I am asking. Is there a login function or code that can use the original salt and how do I get it out of the hashed password in the database to check it and verify the user?

About the answer (bcrypt and randomly generated salts)

How do I extract the original randomized salt from the hashed password stored in the database or do I try to separate it first during registration and save it separately to use during login? I read this not the way it is suppose to work.

Hi martinstoeckli … The link to “compatibility pack “ goes to the PHP manual on “password_hash”, I don’t see any compatibility pack. The algorithm is set by blowfish and it stays the same for every hashed password. Using crypt by itself is weaker then blowfish, but even that dose not solve the login problem I am asking about. I tried that frist.

If anyone has a working login code to use with blowfish ($2a$) algorithm and using any cost value, please post it. It needs to extract the salt from the saved hashed database password to hash the user enter password during login for comparison. Somehow... Using a fixed salt is not recommended so the randomized salt during registration must be extracted somehow from the saved hash password.

Hi deceze,

I did check the duplicate but it had no login code to try. I will try to make a new code to test using this one line below… where $passwordToCheck is the login password and $2y$10$abcdefg... is the stored hashed password in the database. I will put it in an “if statement and echo if it is true or else false”. Get back to you with the results…Thanks

```
crypt($passwordToCheck, '$2y$10$abcdefg...')
```

deceze,

I tried this code below with the “,” and “==” both return true or “worked!” with any password input into the login. Please post the code you use for your login page so I can test or modify it to use on mine .

```
if 
(crypt($user_password == $db_password_hash)){
echo '<br>';
echo ' Worked! ';
echo '<br>';
}
else 
{
echo '<br>';    
echo ' Did not work ):  ';
echo '<br>';
}
```

Also I am using “$2y$11$” now for the algorithm and cost parameter on my registration page with database input like this “$2y$11$9MUd40QqfmmtPaes91OttOlvAhkAtMvS4.mtg9LT.tazythwhRMwu”

Would someone please remove the post that this question has been answered. This will just frustrate others trying to fine an answer to this problem as I have been for days now. Again if anyone does have a working code to answer this question please post it so this problem can get resolved for others STILL NEEDING A REAL WORKING ANSWER!

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EUREKA! “I found it” or at least learned how to write the code.

This is A REAL WORKING ANSWER! , The Blowfish login code I wish I had days ago, when I sill had hair!

The "$2y$" is better for PHP 5.3.7 or higher but I must use the "$2a$" algorithm for PHP 5.3 as explained below from http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php.

Versions of PHP before 5.3.7 only support "$2a$" as the salt prefix: PHP 5.3.7 introduced the new prefixes to fix a security weakness in the Blowfish implementation. Please refer to » this document for full details of the security fix, but to summarise, developers targeting only PHP 5.3.7 and later should use "$2y$" in preference to "$2a$".

```
<?php
//  Blowfish login code to verify user login password with the hashed password in database

// Make variables from login form on another page and use “include()” to get this PHP code
$user_name_from_login = $_POST[ 'login_user_name' ];
$user_password_from_login = $_POST[ 'login_password' ];

//Check users name for match in your database table of user names
// You must use a line like this “include(‘your_conection_name.php');” 
//at the top of your page to get the database connection code or add it directly to this page for this to work
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE user_name=:login_user_name";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':login_user_name'=>$user_name_from_login ) );
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 

//Get hashed password in database associated with user name and make it into a php variable
foreach( $results as $row ){ 
$database_password_hash = $row[ 'password' ];
}

//Using the Blowfish “$2a$” algorithm with a cost of  “11$” and random salt form registration  page 
// this one line converts login password to the original saved hashed so it  can be compared with the one saved in database
$user_password_rehashed = crypt($user_password_from_login, $database_password_hash);

//Now a simple comparison can be made and verified with an “if else” using the variables above
if 
($user_password_rehashed == $database_password_hash) {
echo '<br>';
echo ' User’s login password “IS A MATCH” with the one in database (:';
echo '<br>';
}
else 
{
echo '<br>';    
echo ' User’s login password “DOES NOT MATCH” with the one in database ):';
echo '<br>';
}

//Check your output to better understand process 
echo '<br>';
echo ' $user_password_from_login = ' . $user_password_from_login;
echo '<br>';
echo ' $user_password_rehashed --- = ' . $user_password_rehashed;
echo '<br>'; 
echo ' $database_password_hash ---  = ' . $database_password_hash;
echo '<br>';
?>
```

I hope this will save time and money for other web designers…

Comment: Why are you running your hash from the database through `better_crypt` again?!

Comment: You can use the [compatibility pack](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) even with PHP 5.3., you just have to change the algorithm. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15091219/575765). An example using the crypt() function directly, you can find [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php_de.html#bcrypt).

Comment: Have you read the duplicate I linked to? You don't "extract" the salt from the hash. You just feed the hash from the database back into `crypt` as the salt value.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it would be better to use PHP 5.5 with password hash () and password verify() but PHP 5.3 doesn’t seem to recognize them…

Use the [`password_compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library. It provides those functions for PHP 5.3.7 and later.

The problem with your `better_crypt()` function is that it generates a new random salt every time it is called, so the results can't be verified. To be compatible with `crypt()`, it would need to take a salt from another password hash as input.

But don't do that. Use `password_compat`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response duskwuff. Could you post the password_compat. Login code to use with blowfish so I can try it?

Comment: Also I am restricted to PHP 5.3 not 5.3.7